# Plotting a quantity-based function doesn't work

Tags: plotting, units

Creating the function:

```
L := Quantity[15, "Millimeters"]
R := Quantity[2.5, "Millimeters"]

B[z_] := Quantity[1, 
   "Ampere"]*6*(Quantity[1.2566*10^-6, "Newtons"/"Amperes"^2]/
    4)*((z - L/2)/((L/2)*Sqrt[R^2 + (z - L/2)^2]) - (z + L/2)/((L/2)*
       Sqrt[R^2 + (z + L/2)^2]))
```

So far everything works fine - manually evaluating the function gives the expected result:

```
B[Quantity[10, "Millimeters"]]

(* Out: Quantity[-7.1084*10^-8, ("Newtons")/("Amperes" "Millimeters")] *)
```

But when I try to plot it, the result is empty...

```
Plot[B[z], {z, Quantity[-15, "Millimeters"], Quantity[15, "Millimeters"]}]
```

Using Reap/Sow to analyze the evaluation gives a pretty strange result:

```
Reap[
 Plot[B[z], {z, Quantity[-15, "Millimeters"], Quantity[15, "Millimeters"]}, 
  EvaluationMonitor -> Sow[z]]]

(* Out: 
{(empty diagram), {{z, z, 
   Charting`Private`pvar$213225}}} *)
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening here, and how I can get a quantity-based plot? Multiplying the "z" in the function declaration with `Quantity[1, "Millimeters"]` and plotting over real z values returns a diagram, but I'd prefer to be able to use the `Quantity` system...

Comment: Try `Plot[B[Quantity[z, "Millimeters"]], {z, -15, 15}]` instead.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: What mathematica version/OS are you using?

Comment: You must have done something wrong then, cause it does work here: [`Plot[B[Quantity[x, "Millimeters"]], {x, -15, 15}]`](https://i.imgur.com/9icYeQZ.png). I'm on Win10-64 with MMA 12.0. But in all honesty: the `Quantity` framework is not always worth the hassle, in my opinion.

Comment: I would also recommend that you define your constants with `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`). There is no need to re-evaluate a constant every time you use it; that will only slow down your code.

Comment: OK, now it does work ... somehow the function had aquired "mm" as a factor to all the 'z' without me changing anything about it - using plain Plot[B[z]] did start working then (with z specifying the amount of mm). After re-executing the function definition, your code did work - but now I'm curious as to how my function had aquired the "mm" multipliers to all the occurences of the variable...

Comment: @sh4dow Can you explain that last point better? You could also rework your question to include it, since it has no answers yet, or close / delete this question and ask a new one regarding your new issue.

Comment: @MarcoB I wasn't aware how wolfram alpha notebook edition notebooks shared the same kernel - I modified the function by multiplying all "z" manually with Quantity[1,"mm"] so I could plot it by inputting reals. The "isolated" test notebook reflected that change since the function names were identical, and this caused a lot of confusion for me (apparent behavioral inconsistency).
JasonB. solved my issue, and the rest was just me confusing myself.